# Include digital certificate in AppStore-distributed iOS app

Tags: ios, security, client, digital-certificate

I have an endpoint in which the server has to be sure of the authenticity of the client making the API calls. I therefore imagined the best way to do it is to include something like a digital certificate or a secret in the client which would have to be encrypted and distributed within the binary that goes to the AppStore. How could I add such a certificate in order for it to be safe? What alternatives would I have if not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple [helpfully provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/KeyManagementAPIs/KeyManagementAPIs.html) a set of APIs that would allow you to store a certificate securely, and that would probably be what you should use. Past that, there is no way to guarantee that your certificate is not stolen by a sophisticated attacker; any key you distribute can be stolen, unless you are transmitting it over a secure channel to a trusted recipient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think the issue remains because I would have to send the certificate over the internet and store it on the device, where it would be vulnerable to theft. So there is no way of storing a private key on a user's device securely, which makes sense.